# Relationship between Docker --storage-opt size and actual container disk usage

Tags: docker, storage, docker-container

I want to set disk usage quotas for our Docker containers, and I am trying to determine reasonable limits based on current usage.  My plan is to use the `--storage-opt size=` option to set the limits, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what to check on the running containers to find out how much space they're currently using, expressed as a number that directly relates to what I will set in `--storage-opt size=`.

Example:

If my container is currently using X GB of disk space, and I want to give it a Y GB buffer, then I want to set `--storage-opt size=Z`, where Z=X+Y

I can decide on a reasonable value of Y, but I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly to check on the running container to get the current value of X.

[The docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-storage-driver-options-per-container) say that `--storage-opt size=` sets "the container rootfs size".

How exactly do I find the current rootfs size of a running container?

I thought maybe it was the number returned by running `du -h -d 0 /` inside the container.  However, I'm skeptical of this because this number includes the size of a very large shared data drive that's mounted to the host, so it's not really container-specific.  Is that really the right number, and as such I have to include the the size of the shared drive when setting the size quota of every container that mounts it?  I hope not, because I really don't care how much data is stored on this shared drive, and it will grow over time.  I only want to ensure that the storage inside the actual containers remains small and DOES NOT grow significantly over time.

Assuming that the above `du` command is not what I need, what should I actually check instead?

Note: I'm using the overlay2 storage driver with xfs as the backing filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more testing, I found the following.  I'm not 100% sure if it is accurate for all storage drivers, but it appears to work this way in our Docker environment, using the `overlay2` storage driver with `xfs` as the backing filesystem.

The limit that is imposed by the `--storage-opt size=` option is a limit on only the additional storage that is used by the container, not including the Docker image size or any external mounted volumes.  The easiest way that I found to check how much additional storage each container is using the
`docker ps --size` command.

Example output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                CREATED        STATUS          PORTS        NAMES            SIZE
d35144402a2    aspecialdockerimage   "/startmyservice..."   20 hours ago   Up 33 minutes                processing_svc   7.83MB (virtual 11.6GB)
```

The first number in the “size” column in the output is the amount of extra space that the container is using, and can be used as a guide as to how much space the container needs when determining an appropriate quota.  Note that the “virtual” number to the right in parentheses includes the size of the docker image and should not be considered when choosing a quota size.

So, in the example that I gave in my original question the value of X would be 7.83MB, and if I wanted to give it an additional buffer (Y) of 1.17MB, for a total of 9MB (Z), then I would use `--storage-opt size=9M`